# Referencing Visual Basic Power Pack for ShapeContainer and LineShape

Tags: c#, vb-power-pack

I have some old code from Visual Basic Powerpack which I want to use in some C# projects (Framework and Core).

I was able to install Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.3.0 using Nuget

However Nuget does not have an option to install the Powerpack

I get

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ShapeContainer' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Both projects reference a package Microsoft.VisualBasic V10.3.0 
Both projects are C#

I notice that the .Net Core project references a Framework Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms

Is there a way I can get the code working in the C# projects?

Comment: Ideally all of these comments and links would have gone in the question

Comment: OK. I stopped "working out loud"

Comment: They were good, however its better just to put them in the question

Answer (score 0):

I found Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll File version 12.0.21005.1
Then I added it as a reference to the solution and set the build action to Embedded Resource with Copy if newer

This works with Framework 4.7.2 and also with .Net Core 3.1